# Windows Load Balancing Services and File Shares

Tags: windows-server-2008, wlbs

We are using Windows Load Balancing Services (WLBS).  One of the things that I do notice, is that if I create a File Share on one of the physical hosts, I am able browse to that file share using the clustered-ip address.  This might be a 'opinion' question, but I haven't been able to find much literature on file shares in particular with wlbs.  Is this a recommendation configuration?  Are there any limitations?  What about when the share contains different sets of content on both hosts?

For instance:
Three 'hostnames' - host1 (physical1), host2 (physical2), and cluster.

I create the following shares:
\physical1\myshare
\physical2\myshare

What I notice is that i can see:

\cluster\myshare

I'm guessing that this is read-only, and that there's no file synchronization.  But what happens if they are in fact out of sync, what would a network browser see then?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

it sort of depends are what you are trying to accomplish.

high availability file sharing is usually accomplished using microsoft clustering.  this requires some sort of shared storage (i.e. SAN, shared scsi, etc).

another option for file shares is DFS. using dfs, you can get server to server replication and has fault tolerance.